# How to find the total packets of data used by a particular website?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I am using a particular website and I want to know how much packets of data is totally used by the particular website alone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Chrome you can:

1. Press F12
2. Open the network tab.
3. Reload the website.
4. At the bottom is says how much data has been transfered.
5. Profit.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want https://www.wireshark.org or similar. The network tab answer will give you bytes, but to really see what's going on you need a packet sniffer (latency questions may hinge for example on the number of requests spawned by a page rather than the raw byte count).